# another greeting aside from "I hope you are well" in an email?

Tags: greetings

I'm stuck with "I hope you are well" every time I compose an email. What other similar opening lines can I use in an email?

Comment: Just for the record, you may have a look at this https://www.grammarly.com/blog/i-hope-youre-doing-well/

Answer (score 43):

Casually:

> "Hope you're doing well/great."
>
> "Hope your day is going well."
>
> "Hope this email finds you well/in good shape."

Less casual, but informal:

> "I hope you're/you are doing well/great."
>
> "I hope your day is going well."

A bit more formal:

> "I hope this email finds you well/in good shape."

Comment: Why do you think [this article](https://blog.harwardcommunications.com/2012/11/06/how-to-start-emails/) advises against using `I hope this email finds you well` ?